# Check for password before accessing content in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to build a functionality where users have to enter the passcode to access the site.

If you go to this site it will ask for a password (123) before showing you the content:
https://www.protectedtext.com/djangoproj

I want to do it without forms.py.

**URL OF THE PAGE --> TEMPLATE --> ASK FOR PASSCODE --> SHOW CONTENT IF PASSCODE MATCHES**

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Text(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug
```

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Text
import django.contrib.auth
# Create your views here.

def textview(request, slug):
    obj= Text.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'text/textpage.html', {'obj' : obj})

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'text/index.html', {})
```

I have tried creating a new template for password but I am still not getting that functionality.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If I were you (and didn't want to use [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)), I would make something like this:

```
def check_password(*args, **kwargs): # decorator function for checking password
    def wrapper(func):
        if kwargs.get('password', None) == '123':
            func() # show index, if password is corrent
        else:
            raise Exception('Access denied') # else raise the exception
    return wrapper

def home(request):
    try:
        password = request.GET.get('password') # get password from given parameters
        @check_password(password)
        def show_index(): # create function, maybe better to make it out of scope
            return render(request, 'text/index.html', {})
        show_index() # call function
    except:
        print('Password was not given or it is incorrect, access denied')
        return render(request, 'text/401.html', {})
```